# Is it possible to share a virtual machine between two host operating systems?

Tags: virtualbox, vdi

I have Windows 7 and Linux Mint installed on two separate partitions, and I'd like to access a  virtual machine (.vdi) from either of the two partitions. Is it possible for Virtualbox to access a virtual machine that is stored on a separate hard disk partition (e. g., booting a virtual machine that is saved on Windows while running Linux as the host OS)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. As long as both hosts can see the file, just create a virtual machine, and attach he existing hard drive file. For this set up, out the file on the Windows side

Comment: How can I "out the file" on the "Windows side"? What do these phrases refer to, specifically?

Comment: Out the file is phone text for put the file. Put it where Windows can access it, as Windows can't read Linux partitions natively, without extra tools